# Upload a file into a web page using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to upload a file into a web page. I followed the following steps:

1. Open the webpage
2. looking for "input" tagname
3. once tagname is found, open the browser
4. Enter the file path name in the file location.
5. Exit loop.

Problem:
At step-3, once the file browser is opened, the loop is expected a return from the browser.

I tried with the *WScript* after opening the browser but no luck.
If anyone has solution please suggest.

```
Sub File_Test()
    
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim btnInput As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim pointer As Integer
    
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/input-file.html"
    
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLDoc = ie.document
    Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
   
    For Each HTMLButton In HTMLButtons
        For Each btnInput In HTMLButtons
            If btnInput.Type = "file" Then
                HTMLButton.Click
                btnInput.Value = "C:\temp\test.txt"
                pointer = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next btnInput
    
        If pointer = 1 Then Exit For
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

Check out: **Excel upload a file to an FTP site**

http://sam308.com/excel-upload-file-ftp-site